# Multiple slf4j bindings maven stormcv

Tags: java, maven, apache-storm

I'm trying to deploy example 1 of Stormcv (GrayScaledTopology) onto a remote cluster, but I'm always getting multiple slf4j binding issues.

```
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/apache-storm-0.9.3/lib/logback-classic-1.0.jar/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/Angel/Downloads/StormCV-master/stormcv-deploy/target/stormcv-deploy-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
```

this is my pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>nl.tno.stormcv</groupId>
    <artifactId>stormcv-deploy</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Deploy Boilerplate</name>
    <description>Boilerplate project to support developers with packaging of their StormCV topologies</description>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>StormCV repo</id>
            <url>http://github.com/sensorstorm/maven/raw/master/releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nl.tno</groupId>
            <artifactId>stormcv</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>cs.qos.logback</groupId>
                        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>cs.qos.logback</groupId>
                        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.2-incubating</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>stormcv-deploy-${project.version}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>java</executable>
                    <includeProjectDependencies>true</includeProjectDependencies>
                    <includePluginDependencies>false</includePluginDependencies>
                    <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.1</version>
                <configuration>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

this is my deps. tree

```
C:\Users\Angel\Downloads\StormCV-master\stormcv-deploy>mvn dependency:tree
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for nl.tno.stormcv:stormcv-deploy:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 88, column 12
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Deploy Boilerplate 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ stormcv-deploy ---
[INFO] nl.tno.stormcv:stormcv-deploy:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- nl.tno:stormcv:jar:0.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org:opencv:jar:2.4.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- xuggle:xuggle-xuggler:jar:5.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:jar:1.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.8.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.8.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-bundle:jar:1.18:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.storm:storm-core:jar:0.9.2-incubating:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.clojure:clojure:jar:1.5.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- clj-time:clj-time:jar:0.4.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- compojure:compojure:jar:1.1.3:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.clojure:core.incubator:jar:0.1.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.clojure:tools.macro:jar:0.1.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- clout:clout:jar:1.0.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- ring:ring-core:jar:1.1.5:provided
[INFO] |  |     +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.1:provided
[INFO] |  |     \- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] |  +- hiccup:hiccup:jar:0.3.6:provided
[INFO] |  +- ring:ring-devel:jar:0.3.11:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- clj-stacktrace:clj-stacktrace:jar:0.2.2:provided
[INFO] |  +- ring:ring-jetty-adapter:jar:0.3.11:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- ring:ring-servlet:jar:0.3.11:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.26:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api:jar:2.5-20081211:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.26:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.clojure:tools.logging:jar:0.2.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.clojure:math.numeric-tower:jar:0.0.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.clojure:tools.cli:jar:0.2.4:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-framework:jar:2.4.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-client:jar:2.4.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.5:provided
[INFO] |  |     +- jline:jline:jar:0.9.94:provided
[INFO] |  |     \- org.jboss.netty:netty:jar:3.2.2.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.twitter:carbonite:jar:1.4.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.esotericsoftware.kryo:kryo:jar:2.21:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm:reflectasm:jar:shaded:1.07:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:4.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.esotericsoftware.minlog:minlog:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- com.twitter:chill-java:jar:0.3.5:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.11:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.googlecode.disruptor:disruptor:jar:2.10.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jgrapht:jgrapht-core:jar:0.9.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.6:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.6:provided
[INFO] |  \- io.netty:netty:jar:3.6.3.Final:provided
[INFO] \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.801 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-04-11T22:18:28-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/219M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\Angel\Downloads\StormCV-master\stormcv-deploy>
```

As you can see, I've already tried excluding multiple things from the nl.tno package. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

it looks like `slf4j` is in the `org.apache.storm:storm-core` not `nl.tno`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>nl.tno.stormcv</groupId>
    <artifactId>stormcv-deploy</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Deploy Boilerplate</name>
    <description>Boilerplate project to support developers with packaging of their StormCV topologies</description>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>StormCV repo</id>
            <url>http://github.com/sensorstorm/maven/raw/master/releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nl.tno</groupId>
            <artifactId>stormcv</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>cs.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>cs.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.2-incubating</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>stormcv-deploy-${project.version}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>java</executable>
                    <includeProjectDependencies>true</includeProjectDependencies>
                    <includePluginDependencies>false</includePluginDependencies>
                    <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.3</version>
                <configuration>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```